# Open Console app to show Unified Logging logs

Tags: macos, logging

My application uses os_log. When it's done with a task, I display a UserNotification. When the user clicks the notification, I want to display the logs created via through the Apple Unified System Logging.

If I were simply logging to a file, I would execute a Process(NSTask) with something like `open /path/to/mylogs.log` and this would open Console to show the logs. However, I'm using Unified System Logging through the os_log command. What Terminal command can I issue to open Console and have Console display my logs?

Comment: Check the `man` content for the `log` command (`man log` at a Terminal prompt). The section on `collect` discusses creating a `.logarchive` file, which, I believe, can be opened as you describe.